# thread building block combined with pthreads

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp, tbb

I have a queue with elements which needs to be processed. I want to process these elements in parallel. The will be some sections on each element which need to be synchronized. At any point in time there can be max **num_threads** running threads.

I'll provide a **template** to give you an idea of what I want to achieve.

```
queue q

process_element(e)
{
    lock()
    some synchronized area
    // a matrix access performed here so a spin lock would do
    unlock()
    ...
    unsynchronized area
    ...
    if( condition )
    {
        new_element = generate_new_element()
        q.push(new_element) // synchonized access to queue
    }
}

process_queue()
{
    while( elements in q ) // algorithm is finished condition
    {
         e = get_elem_from_queue(q) // synchronized access to queue
         process_element(e)
    }
}
```

**I can use**

- pthreads
- openmp
- intel thread building blocks

**Top problems I have**

- Make sure that at any point in time I have max **num_threads** running threads
- Lightweight synchronization methods to use on queue

My plan is to the intel tbb concurrent_queue for the queue container. But then, will I be able to use pthreads functions ( mutexes, conditions )? Let's assume this works ( it should ). Then, how can I use pthreads to have max num_threads at one point in time? I was thinking to create the threads once, and then, after one element is processes, to access the queue and get the next element. However it if more complicated because I have no guarantee that if there is not element in queue the algorithm is finished.

**My question**

Before I start implementing I'd like to know if there is an easy way to use intel tbb or pthreads to obtain the behaviour I want? More precisely processing elements from a queue in parallel

**Note:** I have tried to use tasks but with no success.

Comment: if its a container of elements, why not use parallel_for to operate on each element. Or use task_group with pop if you must use a queue.

Answer (score 1):

First off, pthreads gives you portability which is hard to walk away from. The following appear to be true from your question - let us know if these aren't true because the answer will then change:
1) You have a multi-core processor(s) on which you're running the code
2) You want to have no more than **num_threads** threads because of (1)

Assuming the above to be true, the following approach might work well for you:

1. Create **num_threads** pthreads using pthread_create
2. Optionally, bind each thread to a different core
3. q.push(new_element) atomically adds new_element to a queue. pthreads_mutex_lock and pthreads_mutex_unlock can help you here. Examples here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~travitch/pthreads_primer.html
4. Use pthreads_mutexes for dequeueing elements
5. Termination is tricky - one way to do this is to add a TERMINATE element to the queue, which upon dequeueing, causes the dequeuer to queue up another TERMINATE element (for the next dequeuer) and then terminate. You will end up with one extra TERMINATE element in the queue, which you can remove by having a named thread dequeue it after all the threads are done.

Depending on how often you add/remove elements from the queue, you may want to use something lighter weight than pthread_mutex_... to enqueue/dequeue elements. This is where you might want to use a more machine-specific construct.

Comment: It is true, I don't want to have more that num_threads running at any point in time. I did what you said, but I have problems at termination. At first, I have used condition variables, but now I just use usleep(), but it still doesn't work. I'll rewrite the code again tomorrow... I wish there was a library that could do this automatically. I noticed threadpool is not implemented in boost ( not officially ), and since 2010 no work has been done.

Answer (score 0):

TBB is compatible with other threading packages.

TBB also emphasizes scalability.  So when you port over your program to from a dual core to a quad core you do not have to adjust your program. With data parallel programming, program performance increases (scales) as you add processors.

Cilk Plus is also another runtime that provides good results.

www.cilkplus.org

Since pThreads is a low level theading library you have to decide how much control you need in your application because it does offer flexibility, but at a high cost in terms of programmer effort, debugging time, and maintenance costs.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to look at `tbb::parallel_do`. It was designed to process elements from a container in parallel, even if the container itself is not concurrent; i.e. `parallel_do` works with an `std::queue` correctly without any user synchronization (of course you would still need to protect your matrix access inside `process_element()`. Moreover, with `parallel_do` you can add more work on the fly, which looks like what you need, as `process_element()` creates and adds new elements to the work queue (the only caution is that the newly added work will be processed immediately, unlike putting in a queue which would postpone processing till after all "older" items). Also, you don't have to worry about termination: `parallel_do` will complete automatically as soon as all initial queue items and new items created on the fly are processed.

However, if, besides the computation itself, the work queue can be concurrently fed from another source (e.g. from an I/O processing thread), then `parallel_do` is not suitable. In this case, it might make sense to look at `parallel_pipeline` or, better, the TBB flow graph.

Lastly, an application can control the number of active threads with TBB, though it's not a recommended approach.